# servicio web json twitter

Tags: android

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación para buscar un perfil en twitter a través de un servicio web Json, estoy buscando en la api oficial de twitter la uri para poder mostrar el perfil de un usuario determinado.
Yo utilizo esta:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterdev
>
> *(Ejemplo de la documentación oficial)*

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

No se si es la uri adecuada o si me falta hacer algo más.

Comment: Antes de poder realizar consultas contra la API tienes que autentificar tu aplicación usando los token que la consola de desarrollador de Twitter te proporciona.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, ya he conseguido autentificar mi aplicación en twitter.  Ahora disculpen mi ignorancia, pero no se como identificarme para poder introducir Consumer Key y el Consumer Secret y poder hacer la peticiones

Comment: Pues eso depende de como lo estés haciendo, del lenguaje, librerías, etc... Abre una nueva pregunta y especifica más las tecnologías que utilizas, describe la situación y muestra lo que hayas intentado.